# xgps cannot handle gpsd ..gpsmon works ok

Tags: networking, bluetooth, gps

after binding my mobile-gps
I can't start xgps with error.

gpsmon /dev/rfcomm0 works ok.
My hard-wired gps works ok, as well!!

My procedure getting the error messages:

```
$ sudo rfcomm bind rfcomm0 C0:EE:FB:20:94:C2 7

$ sudo systemctl status gpsd*
 ● gpsd.socket - GPS (Global Positioning System) Daemon Sockets
 Loaded: loaded (/etc/systemd/system/gpsd.socket; enabled; vendor  preset: enabled)
 Active: active (running) since Sun 2021-03-14 18:32:56 CET; 5min ago
 Triggers: ● gpsd.service
 Listen: /run/gpsd.sock (Stream)
         [::1]:2947 (Stream)
         127.0.0.1:2947 (Stream)
 Tasks: 0 (limit: 18994)
 Memory: 72.0K
 CGroup: /system.slice/gpsd.socket

  Mär 14 18:32:56 OMEN-17cbxxxx systemd[1]: Listening on GPS 
 (Global Positioning System) Daemon Sockets.

  ● gpsd.service - GPS (Global Positioning System) Daemon
 Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/gpsd.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
Active: active (running) since Sun 2021-03-14 18:32:56 CET; 5min ago
  TriggeredBy: ● gpsd.socket
Process: 1300 ExecStart=/usr/sbin/gpsd $GPSD_OPTIONS $DEVICES (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
  Main PID: 1305 (gpsd)
  Tasks: 1 (limit: 18994)
  Memory: 1.5M
  CGroup: /system.slice/gpsd.service
         └─1305 /usr/sbin/gpsd /dev/rfcomm0

Mär 14 18:32:56 OMEN-17cbxxxx systemd[1]: Starting GPS (Global Positioning System) Daemon...
Mär 14 18:32:56 OMEN-17cbxxxx systemd[1]: Started GPS (Global Positioning System) Daemon.

$ xgps
  xgps: host localhost port 2947

$ sudo systemctl status gpsd*

● gpsd.socket - GPS (Global Positioning System) Daemon Sockets
  Loaded: loaded (/etc/systemd/system/gpsd.socket; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
  Active: active (running) since Sun 2021-03-14 18:32:56 CET; 5min ago
  Triggers: ● gpsd.service
    Listen: /run/gpsd.sock (Stream)
           [::1]:2947 (Stream)
           127.0.0.1:2947 (Stream)
  Tasks: 0 (limit: 18994)
  Memory: 72.0K
  CGroup: /system.slice/gpsd.socket

 Mär 14 18:32:56 OMEN-17cbxxxx systemd[1]: Listening on GPS (Global Positioning System) Daemon Sockets.

 ● gpsd.service - GPS (Global Positioning System) Daemon
 Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/gpsd.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
 Active: active (running) since Sun 2021-03-14 18:32:56 CET; 5min ago
 TriggeredBy: ● gpsd.socket
  Process: 1300 ExecStart=/usr/sbin/gpsd $GPSD_OPTIONS $DEVICES (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
  Main PID: 1305 (gpsd)
  Tasks: 1 (limit: 18994)
  Memory: 1.6M
  CGroup: /system.slice/gpsd.service
         └─1305 /usr/sbin/gpsd /dev/rfcomm0

 Mär 14 18:32:56 OMEN-17cbxxxx systemd[1]: Starting GPS (Global Positioning System) Daemon...
 Mär 14 18:32:56 OMEN-17cbxxxx systemd[1]: Started GPS (Global Positioning System) Daemon.
 Mär 14 18:38:37 OMEN-17cbxxxx gpsd[1305]: gpsd:ERROR: SER: device open  of /dev/rfcomm0 failed: Permission denied - retrying read-only
 Mär 14 18:38:37 OMEN-17cbxxxx gpsd[1305]: gpsd:ERROR: SER: read-only device open of /dev/rfcomm0 failed: Permission denied
 Mär 14 18:38:37 OMEN-17cbxxxx gpsd[1305]: gpsd:ERROR: /dev/rfcomm0: device activation failed.
 Mär 14 18:38:37 OMEN-17cbxxxx gpsd[1305]: gpsd:ERROR: /dev/rfcomm0: activation failed, freeing device
```

It seems, that xgps blocks gpsd?!!
gpsmon /dev/rfcomm0 works perfect!!

Comment: @user535733 second try...!

Comment: Check `ls -l /dev/rfcomm0`. The ownership of the device should be root:dialout. If it's not, sudo chown it.

Comment: ls -l /dev/rfcomm0
crw-rw---- 1 root dialout 216, 0 Mär 14 18:38 /dev/rfcomm0